# Problema al integrar jsf en un Button HTML5

Tags: java, html5, jsf

Estoy intentando realizar la conexión de Front-end con el Back-end mediante JSF. Estoy utilizando bootstrap, todo funciona perfecto hasta que inserto el `jsf:action #{action}` en el boton.

EL problema es que después de meter este pequeño fragmento de código el html no carga como se debe.

Agrego el código:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf">

    <!-- BEGIN # MODAL LOGIN -->
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" align="center">
                <img class="img-resize" id="img_logo" src="../resources/images/Icons/logo.png"/>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <!-- Begin # DIV Form -->
            <div id="div-forms">

                <!-- Begin # Login Form -->
                <form id="login-form" jsf:id="form">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div id="div-login-msg">
                            <div id="icon-login-msg" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></div>
                            <span id="text-login-msg">#{msg.Login_GetData}</span>
                        </div>
                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="#{msg.Login_parmIdUsuario}" required="true" type="text" jsf:value="#{mpersonasnjControllerExc.parmIdUsuario}"/>
                        <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="#{msg.Login_parmCodClaveNivel1}" required="true" jsf:value="#{mpersonasnjControllerExc.parmCodClaveNivel1}"/>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox"/> #{msg.Login_Remember}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div>
                            <button type="Submit" jsf:action="#{mpersonasnjControllerExc.IniciaSesion}" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">#{msg.LoginBtnIngresar}</button>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <button id="login_lost_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-link">#{msg.Login_OlvidoPassw}</button>
                            <a id="login_register_btn" type="button" href="/ClubExc/faces/cristyanp/musuarios/Create.xhtml?faces-redirect=true" class="btn btn-link">#{msg.CaratulaPortalRegistrarse}</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <!-- End # Login Form -->

                <!-- Begin | Lost Password Form -->
                <form id="lost-form" style="display:none;">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div id="div-lost-msg">
                            <div id="icon-lost-msg" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></div>
                            <span id="text-lost-msg">Type your e-mail.</span>
                        </div>
                        <input id="lost_email" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail (type ERROR for error effect)" required="true"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Send</button>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <button id="lost_login_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-link">Log In</button>
                            <button id="lost_register_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-link">Register</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <!-- End | Lost Password Form -->

                <!-- Begin | Register Form -->
                <form id="register-form" style="display:none;">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div id="div-register-msg">
                            <div id="icon-register-msg" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></div>
                            <span id="text-register-msg">Register an account.</span>
                        </div>
                        <input id="register_username" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username (type ERROR for error effect)" required="true"/>
                        <input id="register_email" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail" required="true"/>
                        <input id="register_password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" required="true"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Register</button>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <button id="register_login_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-link">Log In</button>
                            <button id="register_lost_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-link">Lost Password?</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <!-- End | Register Form -->

            </div>
            <!-- End # DIV Form -->

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END # MODAL LOGIN -->
</ui:composition>
```

Adjunto imagen de como se ve cuando inserto el fragmento mencionado:

[image: No renderiza nada]

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio @Cristian. Por favor indica cuál es el botón al que le agregas dicha característica y "malogra" el renderizado de la vista.

Answer (score 0):

En JSF `<h:commandButton />` lo que hace es generar un  `<button type="submit" />` por lo que debería funcionar:

```
<button type="submit" 
        jsf:action="#{mpersonasnjControllerExc.IniciaSesion}" 
        class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">
                         #{msg.LoginBtnIngresar}
</button>
```

Sin embargo debe haber algún stacktrace o warning en tal caso que no funcione.

Yo personalmente utilizo bootstrap directamente en los componentes, para eso está  `styleClass`:

```
<h:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" 
                 action="#{mpersonasnjControllerExc.IniciaSesion}" 
                 value="#{msg.LoginBtnIngresar}"/>
```

Normalmente `jsf:atributo` se utiliza cuando no existe un componente JSF pero sí HTML5 como `<video ...>`